# Trying to solve limits in a loop for a game (shots in bidimensional array)

Tags: java, loops

The thing is that I have a couple of methods to do a shot in a board on java. You can modify the array size in the code, and it works for any dimension. You can choose many different shoot directions. For example, if a[x][9] , you can shoot from -4 to 4(not 0). The thing is that it works for all directions in all dimensions but not for the limits (-4 and 4 in this case).

I suppose the problem must be in the constants, but Im not sure. I paste here the code for you to be able to compile ; )

```
public class Shooting{

    public static char [][] b = new char [25][9];

        public static char EMPTY = '-';
        public static char SHOT = 'x';
        public static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        public static int shootDirection;
        public static int BOTTOM = b.length - 1;
        public static int RIGHT_WALL = b[0].length - 1;
        public static int LEFT_WALL = 0;
        public static int TOP = 0;
        public static int CENTER = ((RIGHT_WALL)/2);
        public static int START = ((RIGHT_WALL)/2) + shootDirection;

        public static void fill (char [][] b){
            for (int x = 0; x < b.length; x++){
                for (int y = 0; y < b[x].length;y++){
                    b [x][y] = EMPTY;
//                  b [10][y] = 'A';
                }
            }
        }    
        public static void show (char [][] b){
            for (int x = 0; x < b.length; x++){
                System.out.println();
                for (int y = 0; y < b[x].length; y++){
                    System.out.print(" "+b [x][y]+" ");
                }       
            }
        }
        public static boolean isOut (int x,int y){
            if(x < TOP)return true;
            if(y > RIGHT_WALL)return true;
            if(y < LEFT_WALL)return true;
            return false;     
        }
        static boolean emptyCell(int i, int j){
              return b [i][j] == EMPTY;
            }
        public static void shootDude (char [][] a , int shootDirection){
            START = ((RIGHT_WALL)/2) + shootDirection;
            boolean shotRight = false;
            if(shootDirection < 0)
                shotRight = false;
            else if(shootDirection > 0)
                shotRight = true;
            for(int i = a.length-1,j = START ;i >= 0;--i) {
                if(!isOut(i,j) && !emptyCell(i,j)) break;
                if(!isOut(i,j) && shotRight) {
                    a[i][j] = SHOT;
                    ++j;
                }
                else {
                    a[i][j] = SHOT;
                    --j;
                }
                if(j <= LEFT_WALL) 
                    shotRight = true;
                if(j >= RIGHT_WALL) 
                    shotRight = false;
            }
        }

        public static void main (String[] args){
            System.out.println("Introduce shot direction:");
            // With b[x][9] you can shot from -4 to 4. The thing is that 
            //it doesnt work for -4 and 4, the edges. Can anyone solve it? 
            // Must be a silly thing ;)
            int shootDirection = sc.nextInt();
            fill (b);
            shootDude(b,shootDirection);
            show(b);


        }
}
```

Must import Scanner ;)

Comment: Any way you can come up with a minimal failing example (preferably with a failing test case)? Also, it's confusing to use (x,y) to mean (distance from top, distance from left), as (x,y) usually means (horizontal, vertical).

Comment: I know x and y means horizontal and vertical. I dont want to mean distance, just positions ;)

Comment: "Any way you can come up with a minimal failing example (preferably with a failing test case)?" I said in the post that you can try -4 and 4, and you'll get a fail ;)

Comment: The line `if(x < TOP)` seems to confuse `x` and `y` in terms of horizontal and vertical. At first glance, it looks like you're consistent in using `b[vertical_coordinate][horizontal_coordinate]`, but this makes reading the code more difficult. Try narrowing down the method that causes the error by unit testing each method. For example, are you sure `isOut` works correctly for all edge cases (including points below the bottom)?

Comment: I'll take a look,then I tell you, thanks for answering.

Comment: Letters and their names have nothing to do with the problem. I've check them, and they are properly labeled. Think that I could hve labeled them has cc and uu for example.

Comment: Agree, they're just names, but they make it harder to read through the code and offer advice. For example, when I look at the `shootDude` function, not only is it not clear what this is doing, it's unclear what the logic is *supposed* to be. If the logic is: _start at a square_, _keep going in the direction until you hit a wall_, _and return if you hit an object_, then make the code read as such: `while (!isOut(currentSquare)) { if isHit(currentSquare) return true; else currentSquare = move(direction); } return false;`  (or something along those lines)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As simple as modifying the use of the boolean condition inside if loops ;)

```
public static void shootDude (char [][] a , int shootDirection){
        START = ((RIGHT_WALL)/2) + shootDirection;
        boolean shotRight = false;
        if(shootDirection < 0)
            shotRight = false;
        else if(shootDirection > 0)
            shotRight = true;
        for(int x = BOTTOM,y = START ;x >= 0;x--) {
            if(!isOut(x,y) && !emptyCell(x,y)) break;
            if(y <= LEFT_WALL) 
                shotRight = true;
            if(y >= RIGHT_WALL) 
                shotRight = false;
            if(!isOut(x,y) && shotRight == true) {
                a[x][y] = SHOT;
                ++y;
            }
            if(!isOut(x,y) && shotRight == false){
                a[x][y] = SHOT;
                --y;
            }
        }
    }
```